# Using a helper method to insert html into document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Using twitter bootstrap for our rails 4 app, I want to create a helper function to add a link to the page that, when clicked, will produced a modal popup that renders the show template. I think I'm close though, when the page that this function is called from loads, the button is properly displayed, but when clicked, it produces a modal with the raw ruby injection, like this:

```rb
<%= render :template => 'imprintables/show', locals: { modal: true, id: 1 } %>
```

My problem is that instead of the displaying the injection, I'd like the ruby injection to be preformed. Also general style advice and other pointers/criticism would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def imprintable_modal(imprintable) raw %(
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click for Imprintable Info</a>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= render :template => 'imprintables/show', locals: { modal: true, id: #{imprintable.id} } %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, and the content of template 'imprintables/show' need not to be loaded dynamically (through ajax), then I suggest to use plain old templates.

app/views/application/_modal.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 text-right">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click for Imprintable Info</a>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= render :template => 'imprintables/show', locals: { modal: true, id: #{imprintable.id} } %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the in application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def imprintable_modal(imprintable)
    render :partial => 'modal', :locals => { :imprintable => imprintable }
  end
end
```

Comment: I was just about to post that I had figured this out but you beat me to it! I think I've just been stuck thinking in one way when this answer is so painfully obvious. Thanks for the response!